# Primeng datatable error 'classList' of null in editable mode

Tags: angular, primeng

In my angular 4 project I am using primeng datatable, when I try to edit one cell and press enter I have this error:

> Cannot read property 'classList' of null
>       at DomHandler.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/dom/domhandler.js.DomHandler.removeClass
>   (domhandler.js:35)
>       at DataTable.webpackJsonp.../../../../primeng/components/datatable/datatable.js.DataTable.switchCellToViewMode

My method onEditComplete works good and the edit works fine, but the field still in edit mode and I don't know why I have this error

**primeng.html**

```
<p-dataTable #dt [value]="models" [rows]="10" [editable]="true"
(onEditInit)="loadVersion($event)"
(onEditComplete)="saveEdit($event)" [paginator]="true"
[rowsPerPageOptions]="pageSizeOptions" [responsive]="true"
resizableColumns="true" [lazy]="true"
[totalRecords]="totalElements" (onLazyLoad)="loadTable($event)"
reorderableColumns="true"> <p-column field="type"
header="tickettype"
[editable]="true" [sortable]="true"></p-column> </p-dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in v4.1.3

[Bug 3553](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/3553)